# Fetching GPS/Geo Location Information via AsyncTask

Tags: android, gps, android-asynctask

I need some guidance; Im trying to get the gps/geo location in the background via AsyncTask; so here is my scenario. i have a class that does the network/gps checking and lat+long fetching. and in my main activity, i wanna call it and restive that information. however this code is not working. any ideas?

p.s.

the progressbar circle is not appearing as well!

```
package com.parspake.kookojapost;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.ThumbnailUtils;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainAct extends Activity {

ProgressBar pg;
ConnectionHandler mNet;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mNet = new ConnectionHandler(this);

//        pg.setIndeterminate(true);
//        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


//        new FetchLocation().execute();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    new FetchLocation().execute();

}


private class FetchLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (mNet.locationSourceEnabled()) {
            Log.d("kookojaPost","mLat is: " + mNet.mLat);
//               while (mNet.mLat == 0.0) {
//                   mNet.getLocation();
//               }
            if (mNet.mLat == 0.0) {
                mNet.getLocation();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pg.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
 }
}
```

and my network/gps class:

```
package com.parspake.kookojapost;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.*;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ConnectionHandler {

private Context ctx;
double mLat;
double mLong;
String currCity;
String currCountry;
String mAddress;
LocationManager currentLoc;
LocationListener locLis;

public ConnectionHandler(Context context) {
    this.ctx = context;
}

public boolean internetAccess() {
    ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = con.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // Simplified: return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean locationSourceEnabled() {
    currentLoc = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean isInternetLocationAvailable = currentLoc.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    boolean isGpsAvailable = currentLoc.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (isInternetLocationAvailable) {
        Log.d("kookojaPost", "internet location avaiable");
        return true;
    } else if (isGpsAvailable) {
        Log.d("kookojaPost", "gps location avaiable");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void getLocation() {

    locLis = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    currCity = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    currCountry =  addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    mAddress = currCity + " - " + currCountry;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("kookojaPost", e.getMessage());
                }
                String s = "Loction: \n" + mAddress;
            Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Location GPS: " + location.getLatitude() + " - " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mLat = location.getLatitude();
            mLong = location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
    };

    currentLoc = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationSourceEnabled()) {
        if (currentLoc.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            currentLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 50, locLis, Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
        if (currentLoc.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            currentLoc.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 50, locLis, Looper.getMainLooper());
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you are just getting location from your server we need to see the code for the methods you are using to do that in the doInBackground part of your AsyncTask. Also are you getting an error or is it just not working?

Comment: no errors. just the progressbar is not showing during the gps call and also not sure if i implemented the AsyncTask correctly for this task. let me post the network class.

Comment: pretty sure you need to use show and dismiss to actually show the progress bar and not just setVisibility

Comment: dont have these methods for circle progressbar!!